# React native async storage mac OS pod install failing

Tags: react-native

```
Specs satisfying the `RNCAsyncStorage (from `../node_modules/@react-native-async-storage/async-storage`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I have changed the deployment target to 10.15 from xcode, but I still get this

Answer (score 0):

The `RNCAsyncStorage`'s min deployment target is 9.0.

Change the line in podfile to 9 or later. And I suggest marking it to 11

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'
```